# Custom Form With Parts Linked To exisitng Model (ActiveRecord)

Tags: yii

i'm madding a form (Yii framework) that does not represent a database table but it contains a part "mapped" to a database table (like a belong_to relation).

So you can consider a **contact form** in which you can choose to whom send the email with a **dropdown list** that represent **users** in database.
And below you can type your email subject and content.

So here the **contact form is not stored in the database**, so it is not an ActiveRecord instance, but it contains "relation" like an ActiveRecord has.

My question is : How do i build my form class ?

I want to be able to do this in the view :

```
$activeFormWidget->dropdown($form->user, 'name', User::model()->getUsers());
```

Comment: Is your form a `CActiveForm`? Also, what's with the `dropdown` method here? Neither the name nor the parameters match any Yii function related to what you are doing.

Comment: The code is used to display the combo in the view. `$activeFormWidget` was just created before with `$this->beginWidget()`. I don't know what class should my form extends, that's why i'm requesting some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [CHtml::dropdownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#dropDownList-detail) to build `dropdown list` without a `CActiveForm`:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('user', // the input name
                    '', // initial selected value
                    CHtml::listData(User::model()->getUsers(), 'id', 'name'), // your data
                    array()); // htmlOptions
?>
```